# How to identify and select all duplicated entries

Tags: mysql

I have trying to identify and select all dublicated entries filled under an row in my mysql table.

I have tried using this query:

```
SELECT id, link, COUNT(*) 
FROM linkuri
HAVING COUNT(*)>1
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

The problem is that is resulting me 0 results and I've checked manualy few pages and I've seen some dublicates entries.

What I want is to check and delete all dublicated entryes filled under the row link.

Comment: where 's the group statement?

Comment: @ILovePaperTowels can you type me an demo query?

Comment: You have to group by something, otherwise you won't get any results as each row will have a count of 0 or 1. dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/​group-by-functions.htm

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for

```
SELECT a.id, a.link, b.cnt
FROM linkuri
INNER JOIN 
( SELECT link, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM linkuri GROUP BY link HAVING COUNT(*) >1 )b
ON (b.link = a.link)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your query is you're not grouping by anything. To find duplicates you have to group them by a column(s) and then get the count from each group. Having statement is like a where clause on the group http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

```
SELECT id, link, COUNT(*) 
FROM linkuri
GROUP BY link
HAVING COUNT(*)>1
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: is good, but i want to show me with witch id is in dublicated like id1 dublicated with id2       id3 dublicated with id6

Comment: Then use the query from @a1ex07